# How to put an UITextField or UIButton into a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uibutton, uitextfield

I have a NSString i.e. 'Hello Mr <*>. How are you?' and I want to have the <*> as an  UITextField to enter something or an UIButton to call a select list.

What is the best way to do this?

My idea is to count the letters from 0 to '<'-1, this is the start position of the UITextfield. Place the UITextfield via CGRect there. 0 + start position + length of UITextfield is my end position where I place the rest of the string and so on. 
But it will be complicate in respect to lineBreakMode and the different size of letters i.e. length of i vs. m etc.

Any ideas how to put the UITextField into the NSString, that I can work with string as normal?

Comment: What about
UITextFileld *textField ...
[NSString initWithFormat:@"Hello Mr %uitf. How are you.", textField] ? 
That would be perfect :) –

Answer (score 1):

I'd combine `UILabel` with `UITextField` or `UIButton`, there are some frame size calculations to do, but there is nothing to oppose. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Perhaps, Interface Builder could help you to do it effortlessly.

Comment: Actually it is a varied set of phrases, there are no fix positions and places.

Answer (score 1):

NSPredicate might behave like what you described, I don't think it will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, NSPredicate will be the first step to identify the part in the string I need.

But how could I actually place a UIButton in the string - without seperating the string into parts and do something like: label . button . label ... , because of the complex lineBreak/fontsize/character etc. callculations. This solution is not what I am looking for.

Comment: hey Matthias, separating the string might be the best idea given the new "constraint" concept introduced into xcode lately. you don't need to calculate the size, just place them one after another and set constraints on them:)